# Yii2 Query class does not return additional columns

Tags: php, orm, yii2

I've got something like this

```
$query = Customer::find()
                ->select(['customer.name', 'surname', 'cityName' => 'cities.name', 'streetName' => 'streets.name'])
                ->joinWith(['city', 'street'])
                ->where(['group_id' => $id]);
```

When i do

```
return $query->all();
```

it returns only columns from customer table, but when i do something like this

```
$raw = $query->createCommand()->getRawSql();
return \Yii::$app->user_db->createCommand($raw)->queryAll();
```

it returns me all 4 columns. Why orm fails? 
I'm using custom db connection (user), dynamicly connected after authorization. Anyway ActiveRecord->getDb() has been customized too and it works well till now.

Comment: You are working with Active Record in here and must remember that every column is mapped in the model so if you want to get some custom columns you need to declare the corresponding property in `Customer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it returns only columns from customer table, but when i do something like this.

Yes, that's right. Because Yii2 AR(Active Record) is ORM pattern. And it's try to return all result off query like object.

So, I will not tell the theory, I'd better suggest a solution variant:

```
$query = Customer::find()
            ->joinWith(['city', 'street'])
            ->where(['group_id' => $id])
            ->asArray()
            ->all();
return $query;
```

It's from [Yii2 docs(performance tuning)](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-performance-tuning#using-arrays).

The result will be like:

```
[
    all data selected from "customer",
    ['city' => all data selected from city joinWith],
    ['street' => all data selected from street joinWith]
]
```

I think, this is exactly what you need.
**But, if you need objects.** You can try marge objects to only one array.

```
$customer = Customer::find()
            ->joinWith(['city', 'street'])
            ->where(['group_id' => $id])
            ->all();
return [
    'customer' => $customer,
    'city' => $customer->city,
    'street' => $customer->street,
];
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using

```
 ->select(['customer.name', 'surname', 'cityName' => 'cities.name', 'streetName' => 'streets.name'])
```

so you will get selected columns only.
use,

```
 $query = Customer::find()
        ->joinWith(['city', 'street'])
        ->where(['group_id' => $id])
        ->all();
```

this will give you all the columns